# When inserting into a binary tree, is there a universal agreed upon place to insert then new node to minimize complexity?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

Do programmers (in real life), always insert at the top node or somewhere else? Because in my text book CLRS it is not made very clear, so the insertion process can take a best case of O(1), if you insert it just at the right place, or a worst case when you have to rebalance the entire tree.

So in practice is there a place that all new nodes are inserted?

Comment: What kind of binary tree? A plain binary tree isn't balanced at all, for example.

Comment: I don't know about programmers, but computer scientists know several ways of maintaining balanced trees, so *no*. Also, there is no known method that provably *minimises* cost. That said, the initial insertion position is fixed, given the tree, by the new elements position in the sorted sequence. Only *then* do balancing operations happen.

Comment: If you want to insert somewhere other than the root, how do you know where to insert and how do you get a hold of that node? It sounds like you'd end up having another data structure to hold the nodes of your tree to be able to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several different concepts here. Let's start from the most general. A **[tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure)** is a data structure that consists of a root and a collection of children, each of which is a tree. A node of the tree is either the root of the tree itself of a node of the children, i.e. it's the root, or the root of a child, or the root of a child's child, etc. The nodes of a tree can contain information of any type. Here are a few examples of trees:

- One that you encounter everyday when working with computers is the filesystem¹: there's a root directory, subtrees are subdirectories, and there are subtrees which have no children and which are regular files; the children of a node are identified by a name (so it's not “first child”, “second child”, etc. but “child named `hello.txt`, child named `pictures`”, etc.).
- An example from real life is the section structure of a book: there's the book, which is divided into chapters, which are divided into sections, which are divided into subsections, etc.
- One type of tree data structure is the **[trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)**, which stores information indexed by a string. Each node has one child per character in the alphabet. The information corresponding to a string is located by starting from the root, going to the child corresponding to the first character of the string, then to the child of that child corresponding to the second character, etc. For example the string `abc` would be stored three levels deep, going down from the root to the `a` child, then to its `b` child, then to *its* `c` child.

You'll notice that in the filesystem and in the book sections example, information can be inserted anywhere. I can store my files in whichever directory I want; I can add a section to the chapter of my choice. In contrast, the structure of a trie is completely rigid: there's only a single place in the tree where `abc` can go.

A **[binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)** is a tree where each node happens to have at most two children. The two children are typically known as the left and right child. There is a common variation on this definition that defines a binary tree to have two types of nodes: internal nodes which must have exactly two children, and leaves which have no children.

A **[binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)** is a type of tree data structure. Like a trie, it imposes a constraint on where the information must be stored. A trie indexes information by a string; a search tree indexes information that is ordered: it can be numbers, strings, etc. In a binary search tree, the data in the left subtree of a node is always smaller than the datum in the node itself, and the data in the right subtree of a node is always smaller than the datum in the node.

If you try to add element into an existing search tree, there's a single way to do that without changing the current structure of the tree: going down from the root, take the left child if the node is larger than the element to add, take the right child if the node is smaller, and keep going until you get to a child that doesn't exist, and create that child.

However, the structure of search trees is less rigid than the structure of tries: there are different search trees that contain the same data. For example, here are three binary search trees containing the integers 2, 4, 5, 8, 9 (there are of course many more):

```
      8            4          2
    /   \         / \          \
   4      9      2   5          4
  / \               / \          \
 2   5             8   9          5
                                   \
                                    9
                                   /
                                  8
```

In the worst case, inserting an element in a search tree requires traversing the whole height of the tree, which as the last example above show can be as much as the number of elements of the tree.

The leeway in the tree structure allows one to reshape the tree when adding or removing elements from it. This is called **balancing**. Balancing is done in order to keep the height small, which keeps operations such as search, insertion and deletion efficient. There are several variants of **[balanced search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)**, where the balancing operations is designed to keep the height of the tree logarithmic in the number of elements of the tree: $h = O(\log(n))$. The basic principle of a balanced search tree is to keep some information about the height of the subtree in each node; when the height difference between the two children of a node is too large, some nodes are moved from the deeper subtree to the shallower subtree to rebalance. The rebalancing operation costs $O(1)$ at each node and is performed over the path to the element that's being inserted or removed, so its cost over the whole tree is $O(h) = O(\log n)$. This way, search, insertion and deletion in a balanced search tree cost $O(h)$ to find the target location, plus $O(h)$ to rebalance, which is $O(h) + O(h) = O(\log n)$ total.

¹  <sub>In practice filesystems can be more complex than what I'm talking about here. Filesystems with hard links aren't even trees.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There is only one place if you're using a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (also known as an ordered binary tree or sorted binary tree).

```
insert(val, node):
  if current node is null then make a new node out of val
  if val < node.val then node.left = insert(val, left)
  if val >= node.val then node.right = insert(val, right)
```

Inserting at the top is not valid for a binary search tree as it breaks the invariant of such trees, which is that all nodes in the left child are less than the parent value and all nodes in the right child are greater than the parent (or equal in some cases). Without this you just have an overly complicated list.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting note from the Wikipedia article: "Note that the terminology is by no means standardized in the literature." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

So just by saying binary tree all that means is a tree where each node has two children, it doesn't even mean sorted. So in the most basic unsorted and unbalanced binary tree, you can put a new node at the end of any branch you like!

[image]

Now assuming you are not talking AVL or Red-Black, and just a sorted unbalanced binary tree, then if the tree is empty, then you insert at the root. Otherwise you use a method of looking at each node, starting at the root, and if your value is less than the node, go left, if it's more, go right, and when you get to the end of a branch (a leaf), put it there, left if less, right if more. (As noted in an algorithm in another answer)

Of course you say "in real life," in real life you would hardly ever use a simple unbalanced binary tree, the insertion location would be the same but then you would balance (see AVL or Red-Black tree). And in real life a n-ary btree is much more likely the data structure you would use.